# Trying to write code that will display the number 123.456 as Money

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Not sure if this is correct and will give me the result needed.

```
Dim d As Decimal = 123.456D
Dim s As String = d.ToString()
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `String.Format` with the `C` (currency) format specifier:

```
Dim d As Decimal = 123.456D
Dim s as String = String.Format("{0:C}", d)
```

This will convert your decimal to the money string with format specified by client's Regional settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim d As Decimal = 123.456D
Dim s As String = d.ToString("C");
```